# ggplot x axis labels wont go vertical

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

There should be no xaxis lable, I've set is to element_blank() and the lables should be coming out at angles, vertical to the plot not bunched up and unreadable like this.  I have posted my code below I'm not sure whats causing the issue.  Each set of 162 points is related to one variable so each label has been set to appear in the middle i.e. at each multiple of 81 for all 45 independent variables.  thats whats scale_x_continuous is for.  I have no idea why the plot is displaying the 1:n(pvall) I thought I had turned that off with theme(legend.title=element_blank()).

[image]

This is the code that makes it.

```
pvalplot<-function(var, maintitle) {
  
  pvalall<-as.data.frame(c(t(var)))
  pvalall$Sample_Size<-c((1:(5*162)),(1:(11*162)),(1:(3*162)),(1:(5*162)),(1:(13*162)),(1:(3*162)),(1:(5*162)))
  pvalall$Domain<-c(rep("Physical",5*162),rep("Perinatal",11*162),rep("Developmental",3*162),
                   rep("Lifestyle-Life Events",5*162),rep("Parental-Family",13*162),rep("School",3*162),
                   rep("Neighborhood",5*162))
  pvalall$Domain <- factor(pvalall$Domain,
                          levels = c("Physical", "Perinatal", "Developmental", 
                                     "Lifestyle-Life Events", "Parental-Family",
                                     "School","Neighborhood"))
  pvalall[,1]<-ifelse(pvalall[,1]<1e-20,1e-20,pvalall[,1])
  
  names(pvalall)[1]<-"P-Values"
  
  pvalexp.labels= rep("",45*162)
  for (i in c(1:45)){
    j=i*162-81
    pvalexp.labels[j]=rownames(var)[i]
  } #makes list of empyt labels that w
  
  p<-ggplot(pvalall,aes(x = 1:nrow(pvalall), y = -log10(pvalall[,1])))+
    geom_point(aes(color = Domain,size=5),
               alpha = 0.7, size=1)
  p+ylab(expression(atop(" -log10(P-Values)")))+
    ylim(0,20)+
    scale_x_continuous( breaks=c(1:45)*162-81, labels = rownames(var))+
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
    theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 25))+
    theme(text = element_text(size=25))+
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
    theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.7))+
    geom_abline(slope=0,intercept=-log10(c(var)[astsa::FDR(c(var))]),linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_abline(slope=0,intercept=5.2,linetype = "dashed")+
    ggtitle(maintitle)+
    theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    theme(
      legend.box.background = element_rect(),
      legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))+
    annotate("text",  label = expression(paste("FDR P-value","=0.05")),size=5, x=1000,y=-log10(c(var)[astsa::FDR(c(var))])-0.5, color="black",parse=TRUE)+
    annotate("text",  label = expression(paste("Bonferroni P-value","=0.05")),size=5, x=1200,y=5.7, color="black",parse=TRUE)
}#end of plotting

gender="male"
race="white"
tiff(paste("pvalues_",gender,race,".tiff",sep = ""),1400,900)
pvalplot(var = as.matrix(get_pvals(gender, race)),
         "White Males")
```

Comment: Try with `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` instead of using theme_update().

Comment: @stefan almost worked ahah.  That got the tickmark labels on there now I just need to adjust their size because they are kind of crushing the plot.

Comment: Thanks though I think that got me over the hump.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of ggplot2, the `guide_axis()` function provides direct access to label rotation and dodging (which is often more readable) without having to fiddle with themes.